# Target class [App\Http\Controllers\PlayersController] does not exist.と出てしまう

Tags: laravel

**目標**　テストを表示させる
**問題**　Target class [App\Http\Controllers\PlayersController] does not exist.

バージョン　laravel8

**試したこと**
RouteServiceProvider.phpで名前空間を手動で追加する
web.phpで完全な名前空間を使用する
web.phpでアクション構文を使用する

サイトリンク　[参考サイト](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SE8et.png)

現状
・RouteServiceProvider.php
[image: RouteServiceProvider.php]

・web.php
[image: web.php]

・PlyersController.php
[image: PlyersController.php]

他は触っていない。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

クラスのplyersControllerにsが抜けていました。